# Cómo registrar datos según tasa de muestreo

Tags: python, arduino

Necesito implementar un circuito que mida la temperatura de una ampolleta o bombillo con un termistor NTC 100K. En python necesito registrar la temperatura medida y el instante de tiempo en que se realiza el registro, considerando una **tasa de muestreo** de **20 muestras por segundo**.

Luego requiero hacer varias pruebas de medición y adquisición de datos que deben ser durante **intervalos de 60 segundos**.

Hasta el momento, mi código en python que registra los datos es el que se muestra a continuación. Con respecto a ese código debo mencionar lo siguiente:

- Dado que la medición debe hacerse por 1 minuto y la tasa de muestreo es de 20 muestras por segundo, consideré que la cantidad de datos a adquirir en ese tiempo corresponde a 20 muestras * 60 segundos = 1200 datos en total, que es el largo de la lista del código de Python (`numPoints = 1200`)
- Para la variable de tiempo desarrollada en el código de Python, hice una lista y un for simple que va a generar 1200 datos en intervalo de 50, este valor de intervalo es debido a que, por la tasa de muestreo solicitada, cada 50 ms adquiero datos, entonces mi tiempo va desde 0 ms hasta 60.000 ms, por eso el iterador *i* lo multiplico por 50 (`d1 = i*50`)

```
import sys, time, serial
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

time.sleep(3)                # Generar un retardo 3ms
numPoints = 1200            # Cant de datos


with serial.Serial('COM8', 9600) as ser:
    
    def getValues():
        ser.write(b'g')
        tiempo = np.arange(0, 60000, 50)
        arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('ascii','ignore')
        arduinoData_2 = arduinoData.strip(',\r\n')

        return tiempo, arduinoData_2
    
    
    registro = open("exp1_punto22_v3.txt", "w")
    header = "Tiempo, T°"
    registro.write(header + "\n")

    for i in range(0, numPoints):
        data = getValues()
        d1 = i*50 #tiempo
        d2 = data[1] #datos arduino
        datos = str(d1)+ ", " + str(d2) + "\n"
        registro.write(datos)

    registro.close()
```

El código en arduino para el NTC es el que se muestra a continuación y debo mencionar que:

- Para hacer la medición según el muestreo solicitado, en el código de Arduino hice una condición if que me permita gatillar la medición solo en intervalos de 50 ms, para eso generé dos variables, tiempo1 y tiempo2, en donde una corresponde a la función `millis()`, y que será restada a la otra variable, de este modo, cuando la resta sea igual a 50, se gatilla una medición, y la variable de tiempo2 toma el valor de tiempo1 en ese momento, para poder volver a cumplir con la condición y seguir adquiriendo datos cada 50 ms.

```
#define outputPin  6 
#define zerocross  2 
#define termistorPin A0
#define termistorNominalRes 100000
#define termistorNominalTemp 25
#define termistorBValue 4100
#define VoltageDividerResistor 100000

int outVal = 0, ntc, error;
float termistorRes = 0.0, temp, ref;
float steinhart;
unsigned long tiempo1 = 0, tiempo2 = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  tiempo1 = millis();
  tiempo2 = 0;
}

void loop() {
   Serial.println(temp);

  if (tiempo2 - tiempo1 == 50){
  tiempo1 = tiempo2; 
  termistorRes = ((float)analogRead (termistorPin)* VoltageDividerResistor)/(1023 - (float)analogRead (termistorPin));
  steinhart = termistorRes / termistorNominalRes;     // (R/Ro)
  steinhart = log(steinhart);                         // ln(R/Ro)
  steinhart /= termistorBValue;                       // 1/B * ln(R/Ro)
  steinhart += 1.0 / (termistorNominalTemp + 273.15); // + (1/To)
  steinhart = 1.0 / steinhart;                        // Invert  
  steinhart -= 273.15;                                // convert to C
  temp=steinhart;  
}}
```

Actualmente, el código en arduino no genera ningún valor.

> ***Nota***: Cualquier error relacionado a la librería RBDdimmer u otro, obviarlo, ya que este trozo de código es parte de uno más grande relacionado al control de potencia de la ampolleta o bombillo, y que no se incluyó en este post.

Comment: `if (tiempo2 - tiempo1 >= 50)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma correcta de ejecutar un proceso a intervalos en Arduino sin usar interrupciones es:

```
unsigned long tiempo1;

void setup() {

  ... Inicialización de puertas y demases ...

  // Al final de todo, comenzar a contar el tiempo.
  tiempo1 = millis();
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long now = millis();
  if (now - tiempo1 >= 50) {
    tiempo1 = now;
    // Tomar la temperatura 
  }
}
```

En cada `loop` comparas el tiempo actual contra el inicial. Trabajando con milisegundos siempre debes calcular los intervalos por resta y comparar por mayor (o menor) igual, según sea el caso.

El tiempo se toma al inicio de cada ciclo. Cada ejecución dentro del `if` es a intervalos regulares (50 ms), sin importar si un loop en particular toma más o menos tiempo que los anteriores.

También es recomendable ejecutar solo un `millis()` por loop, para asegurar que todos los calculos se refieran a la misma base.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta, @CandidMoe, pero tengo una consulta, al ejecutar el proceso que menciona de intervalos en arduino, ¿debo cambiar la línea `d1 = i*50` en python? Tengo una confusión sobre cómo se prosigue en python, porque requiero registrar el instante de tiempo, si pudiera ayudarme y aclararme el tema, agradecido

Comment: Enviaria el tiempo desde Arduino (en milisegundos) y lo leeria en Python. Eso sería más preciso y flexible.